# Sums of squares in fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-fields, fields, sums-of-squares

Which fields $k$ have the property that *any sum of squares is a square* ? 
Are there elegant characterizations and/or classifications known for this type of field ?

And what if we replace "fields" by "division rings" ?

Comment: This is called a Pythagorean field and has been much studied, see this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_field).